# Wayland performance on video cards

Tags: xorg, wayland

I have read way too many reports/blogs/news about it, but have yet to come up with a way to be sure so I will ask here: Will Wayland have any performance enhancements with video cards (higher FPS, better quality, less resource usage) in comparison to using X?

Updated posts include:

[Ubuntu 13.04 Will Enable Wayland Support In GTK+](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI3MDY)

[Good news in launchpad regarding Wayland Support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/954352)

Comment: Try once steamos, they have wayland. I see a big difference with a new gaming card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wise answer is to say : It's too soon to tell. Wayland is too young. Many bugs where a fix can slow down things.

The logic answer is to say : yes, it will be faster : there is another newer structure, fresh coding, direct help from the professionals... many things that xorg can't do without breaking everything.

Remember when ext4 went. It was a lot faster than ext3. There was a big bug and we lost almost all the performance. Nowaday ext4 is faster but not like when it came first.

Comment: Thanks Antoine, actually I am trying to see if it is something that will actually enhance the performance for all video cards in general, a performance that we can actually see/feel or something along the lines of the "40% faster" but we can see it, feel it or even measure it.

Comment: Check the phoronix home page : http://www.phoronix.com They are quite neutral and they make regular benchmarks. As for the "all video cards" : I'm not sure ... I'm quite sure that it will even support old graphic cards or xorg will be faster.